VBA Code for data organizing and inserting specific number of Blank rows between each date data
In a column I have dates and blank cells in between. I want specific number of blank cells to recur after each date. However presently I do not have equal number of blank cells (in my case six) after each date. I am looking for the VBA code to insert blank rows between two dates so that the number of blank cells equals after each date.
My data looks like this:

I tried the following code:
Sub InsertBlankRowsAfterDates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) ' Adjust the column as needed
    
    Dim requiredBlanks As Integer
    requiredBlanks = 6 ' Set the required number of blank cells after each date
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            Dim blankCount As Integer
            blankCount = 0
            
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 1 To requiredBlanks
                If rng.Cells(i + j, 1).Value = "" Then
                    blankCount = blankCount + 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            
            If blankCount < requiredBlanks Then
                ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + (requiredBlanks - blankCount)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

However, after running the code I have the following result.

But I want the data to appear as below:

I am unable to figure out the problem in the code.

Why are blank rows below "Toluence" but above "Sales"? Can you explain in detail the logic to be used to determine how many rows to insert and where, exactly to insert them?
